# Keyboard shortcut for refactor/selection/editor options in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

In NetBeans IDE where you have an icon appear next to a line of code (for example containing refactoring options) what is the keyboard shortcut to expand that menu?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an image of the icon and menu you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean [*Show Suggestion/Tip/Hint*](http://wiki.netbeans.org/KeymapProfileFor60#Coding_in_Java), `Alt + Enter` (Mac: `Ctrl + Enter`)?

Answer (score 2):

On the menubar, go to Tools->Options->Keymap and you can see the keymap settings for everything and set/change them to whatever you want.